# assertEquals() on two objects

Tags: java, junit

When comparing two objects using `assertEquals()` does it considering looking into the internal structure viz. the properties of the objects?

Suppose I have a class A like following:

```
public class A {
    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private String address;
}
```

And suppose the supplied object's (that is to be compared to an object of `A`) properties are in a different order, then what will `assertEquals()` do? Is there a robust method to do it the other way?

Comment: It's important to be specific-which implementation are you talking about? E.g., what package etc.?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: There's more than one assertEquals. Which one are you taking about?

Comment: JUnit assertEquals().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@JimGarrison is quite right - `assertEquals()` will just call the `equals()` method on your objects to determine equality.

To answer your question, "*Is there a robust method to do it the other way?*",
if you can't properly implement the `equals()` method on your class for whatever reason, and you want to evaluate the equality of objects based on the values of their fields, consider using [EqualsBuilder's `reflectionEquals()` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...-). It is fairly robust, and allows you to exclude whatever fields you want.

To answer your other question, "*suppose the supplied object's properties are in a different order, then what will assertEquals() do?*", all it will do is call the `equals()` method on the other instance. For example, if you call `assertEquals(a, b)`, then that will eventually call `a.equals(b)`. However, if you call `assertEquals(b, a)`, then that will eventually call `b.equals(a)`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation @entpnerd

Comment: np. happy to help. :-)

Answer (score 6):

`Assert.assertEquals()` will use the class' `equals()` method.

If your class overrides `equals()` to do a deep comparison then that's what will be used. If you don't override `equals()` then you'll get `Object#equals()` based on identity equality only.

In other words, YOU decide what `equals()` means.